# Null value is substituted by ''

Tags: php, sql, datetime

If $Time is null, then in the query it is substituted by ''. As a result the query is incorrect. How to avoid this problem?

```
$Time = strtotime($arrivals[$i]["time"]);
if ($Time != null)
{
$Time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $Time);
}

$query="INSERT INTO `Schedule` (`Time`) VALUES('".$Time."');";
```

Result query:

```
INSERT INTO `schedule` (`Time`) VALUES('');
```

BUT SHOULD BE:

```
INSERT INTO `schedule` (`Time`) VALUES(null);
```

Comment: `... else {` replace it with something that's not ""? `}` What *do* you want instead if it is `null`?

Comment: @deceze: else { $Time = ""; } DOES NOT work.

Comment: Should be this: INSERT INTO `schedule` (`Time`) VALUES(null); Otherwise it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `NULL` in the query instead of `'2013-...'`, you obviously have to do a little more.

```
if ($Time === null) {
    $Time = 'NULL';
} else {
    $Time = strftime("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'", $Time);
    //                ^ note the quotes ^
}

$query = "INSERT INTO `Schedule` (`Time`) VALUES ($Time);";
//                                note: no quotes ^   ^
```

Comment: If time is NULL, will that insert a NULL value or the string `NULL`?

Comment: Since I'm leaving out the quotes for "NULL", it's the SQL `NULL` value, not the string `'NULL'`.

Comment: finally, an answer that actually WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**!!
I need to insert the Null or '' value in Date field. when I was passing '' or null in MySQL query it stored 000-00-00 instead of blank or null value. I tried many ways to overcome this issue but at last I have to change the Datatype from Date to Varchar of the field.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO `Schedule` (`Time`) VALUES('".($Time==''?'null':$Time)."');";
```