# MySQL datatime NULL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

It's written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784390/mysql-how-to-insert-null-dates) [[MySQL, how to insert null dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784390/mysql-how-to-insert-null-dates])  ]
that MySQL support NULL in datetime field. I am doing this with Java and get next error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'NULL' for column 'lastvisited' at row 1
```

If I run in phpmyadmin:

```
UPDATE `linksbase` SET `lastvisited`=NULL WHERE 1
```

It is updated.

What is the problemw ith Java code?

```
prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `linksbase` (`lastvisited`) VALUES ('NULL')");
```

If I change statement to

```
prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `linksbase` (`lastvisited`) VALUES (NULL)");
```

Error is

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'lastvisited' cannot be null
```

Comment: If I run in PHP my admin 'UPDATE `linksbase` SET `lastvisited`=NULL WHERE 1', it is updated. When select result is 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: Can you show your schema for the `lastvisited` column? Given the last error message, it certainly *looks* like it can't be null...

Comment: You was right. It's not null here.

Comment: So how does your PHP work then? Different schema?

Comment: Question is closed. Problem was in wrong schema.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, No idea. It's not php, but phpmyadmin. May be it automatically set to 0000-000-00, etc.

Comment: Yes, you can activate strict mode of MySQL in which case NULL would be rejected. PMA does not change the configuration so NULL is transformed to 0000-00-00. JDBC foces strict mode, [see this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23371) (but it is indeed a feature!).