# Prevent adding 0000-00-00 value to DATE type columns in all update/insert operations in already built PHP Application

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a PHP - MySQL application where I have a requirement to convert all stored non date values to **NULL** in a DATE column and in future avoid insertion of 0000-00-00 values to column.In short a DATE column should only have either valid DATE values or NULL.Suppose I have a table with a column type as **DATE** and default value to **NULL**.When I tried to insert data into these column with a non date value, instead of setting the value to **NULL** the column is set as **'0000-00-00'**.So if I have the date value as an empty string or a non valid date string I don't want the value **'0000-00-00'** to get inserted.I am using a MySQLi wrapper class library to connect PHP application with MySQL database.The link is given below.

https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

It is difficult for me to check at each insert/update operation in the application where the date column value is indeed a date value and if not, unset the column or set value of column to **NULL**.So I tried to do something at the place where the insert/update command used by the library (All insert/update commands pass through this library).But there also I should have some predefined information on what tables and what columns are **DATE** type (Probably has to fetch table meta information from information Schema table) at hand to compare and act accordingly.

I have found some similar functionality already in JDBC library like in the thread (Please see the answer with 5 upvotes).

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139896/null-instead-0000-00-00-000000-in-mysql-5-7

So is there anything similar like **zeroDateTimeBehaviour = convertTONull** option in JDBC Driver that we can make use of in PHP - MYSQL connection interface or some conversion thing at DB level.

I am using PHP 5.6 and MySQL Version 5.6.

Edit - Many pointed out the question already has an answer in

[MySQL, how to insert null dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784390/mysql-how-to-insert-null-dates)

But all the answers do not lead to correct solution (not in my case at least) as many answers explains how to tackle problem at each insert/update level but not when the application already has a lot of insert/update commands and I want to modify the current application in least possible effort.I am looking to something like

zeroDateTimeBehaviour = convertTONull option in JDBC Driver

Comment: Side note: Some systems provide `0000-00-00`, others `1970-01-01`

Comment: In this case defaults to 0000-00-00

Comment: Not answering your question right now (might have a stab at it later if I have time though), but were you aware that PHP 5.6 went end-of-life 17 days ago?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL, how to insert null dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784390/mysql-how-to-insert-null-dates)

Comment: @Justinas I earlier saw the same question but the problem is all the answers given there tackle the problem at each insert/update operation.If I were to do so I should end up checking in more than 1000 places.I want something like with least possible effort find a suitable solution.

Comment: @KiranMuralee What if *fastest solution* is to check in 1000 places? Or you can convert date column to simple text...

Comment: @Matt Ok agreed.So do you have any solution if project were upgraded to PHP 7 and MySQL 5.7

Comment: @Justinas for any individual check I need to know if column was DATE type if it was then I need to check if value inside the column is a valid date value, if not I should unset the date or set explicit NULL.May be these operations can be put in a common function and then itself it is overhead I would think.I am thinking of no code change in 1000 areas and do something in the connection interface library (common area where all insert/update statements pass through) or at DB level. I don't know why you marked my question as duplicate since the link provided handles at each insert/update level

Comment: @Justinas I cannot change DATE type.Sorry if my explanation is not understood by you correctly.I need column values having DATE type to hold only valid date values (2012-02-09,2019-01-17) else NULL value. It should not conttain 0000-00-00.

Comment: @Justinas I updated the title and content to make everyone understand the question better.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';`

If that doesn't help you I recommend reading up on `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` [Full List of SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html). Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: Sorry SET GLOBAL sql_mode = ''; does not make any difference.ALLOW_INVALID_DATES doesn't make any sense as my problem is just the opposite (allow only NULL value put in place of 0000-00-00)

Comment: did you try `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode?

Comment: Yes still no use